# Does OS X inherit Linux?

Tags: linux, macos

Can I say `OS X` inherits the architecture of `Linux Kernel` since I notice similarities between linux and OS X in many aspects such as terminal commands and system view.

Comment: As far as I know linux is based on BSD! Am I right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446231/how-close-are-mac-os-x-and-bsd-related

Comment: @A.As, no Linux is not based on BSD.  While many of the GNU tools are used on both systems, the Linux & BSD kernels are very different.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Unix_history-simple.svg/1200px-Unix_history-simple.svg.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I say OS X inherits the architecture of Linux Kernel

No; [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) is a line of graphical [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) which run on the [XNU kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) (which has roots from [4.3BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD#4.3BSD) and the [Mach Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_kernel)). [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), on the other hand, is not an operating system (like OS X) but a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) (like XNU) to which various distributions (like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/)) combine a version of the Linux kernel (often forked) with other packages, including GUI's and various other system tools to give a complete operating system to utilize.

The Linux and XNU kernels are both derived from [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) but both kernels take very different approaches to how they handle the hardware itself as well as how they present those layers to a software developer.

> I notice similarities between linux and OS X in many aspects such as terminal commands and system view.

This is in part due to the UNIX-like nature of the kernels and lines of OS's (i.e. command line driven), so there's a familiar feel for those who work amongst the different OS's.

It's also due to the fact that once Apple embraced more of the [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD)/[Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29) based OS's and started developing the OS X line (vs. their older Mac OS), they made it so you could use an [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) based processor, and thus x86 based software, which meant a lot of Linux and BSD software could be ported to OS X (vs. the software having to all be written specifically to support the [PPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) architecture).

Hope that can help.